# Windows 8, XamlReader cannot Load xaml with custom attached properties

Tags: windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, attached-properties, xamlreader

I have custom control "CustomControl" with custom attached property "CustomAttachedProperty" defined in it. Control works correctly, folowing xaml renders as it suppose to be:

```
<ns:CustomControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:ns="using:MyNamespace">
   <TextBlock ns:CustomControl.CustomAttachedProperty="0" Text="This element causes Parse Error" />
</ns:CustomControl>
```

**Problem starts when I try to load same xaml via XamlReader.Load(). Root of problem is attached property.** Without attached property XamlReader able to load string correctly.

XamlReader.Load called in same assembly, where CustomControl is defined.

Anybody have ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I can't give the complete answer but the problem is with the new xaml platform and the way it handles reflection and metadata. Basically because the xaml platform is native under the covers it doesn't have access to reflection to parse the xaml properly.

The way this is solved is with IXamlMetadataProvider which to be honest is a pain in the ass to implement. Part of the normal build process creates one for your app but it doesn't work properly with xaml reader and your library. You end up needing to implement one yourself. You can the one for your app in the obj/Debug folder in XamlTypeInfo.g.cs.

My solution was to create a small project that had the xaml I was going to parse in App.xaml.cs, let the compiler build the above file and then rip it out to create my own.

If you look at this [commit to Caliburn Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/2a57715be8cb76592e7e520938530ca8b935113d) you can see what I ended up with.

Comment: Thank you very much, Nigel, I'll check suggested code to see if it can be useful for me.